# Will counting unique Ip address give me the actual number of unique users

Tags: google-app-engine, ip-address

I have hosted my app on app engine.  I am downloading the log files that provide me with the IP addresses of the users.

I have run a Python script to find distinct IP addresses.

However the number I get is higher than what I anticipated (around 60,000 in last 24 hours----I expected close to 30,000).

I want to know whether counting distinct IP addresses will give me the exact number of unique users or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There may be multiple users behind the same IP address - for example, home routers often use NAT to allow using multiple computers with the same single IP address that is given by the ISP.

Also, universities and other organizations with a lot of users often use NAT and proxies, which may put hundreds users behind the same IP address. Proxies may sometimes insert header information which shows the original IP address, though not all of them show this information.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so.....  Then how can I possibly get an approximation of the unique users.....Can I somehow obtain the Mac address of the users??? or i there some other way to do so

Comment: Unique IP addresses are as accurate as it gets via the log files. You could try getting users to log in to the site, which would allow an easy way to count the users. You could also initiate a new session each time a user comes to the site for the first time and count these sessions into a database - this could work with users who don't log in.

Comment: Well actually I am running a desktop application.....So asking user to log-in is not feasible......I actually ping the app-engine each time a user opens my application.....

Comment: Ahh - if you try to use this to check for unique installations, you could make the software to create a unique installation id (perhaps create a hash from data such as date + time + username or something else that would make it random enough to avoid creating duplicates). Then just supply this unique id each time with the HTTP request and log it in a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing more IP addresses than you expected, then either your expectations are wrong or else each user is using on average 2 different IP addresses. This would happen for example if your software is installed on a laptop or mobile device, and they're connecting via different wireless networks in different locations.

Comment: Exactly.....Even I believe that a single user may have more than 1 IP addresses because of different networks.....We already have a code that pings to app engine from our client machine........ 
Therefore I wanted to know If somehow I could detect MAC address of a device......
All my research till now suggests that Mac ID can be found only on the local network

Comment: @Mayank: Correct, you can't detect the MAC address from the server side of an HTTP connection. It's hidden behind any NAT, and even if there's no NAT it's hidden at a lower protocol layer than your server's TCP socket exposes. There's one possible exception, that IPv6 addresses include the MAC (or a MAC-like thing, not sure) in their least significant digits. There's no guarantee that the machine won't keep changing those digits for the sake of privacy, though, each time it connects to a new network. Client software could look up the MAC, though, and include it in the unique installation ID.